# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, image, pdo

I am doing small project, where profile picture need to be updated by the user (There are 9 fields in the tbl_users, out of 9, only need to update 1 field (location) for image, So, I have code in PDO,  have error during image filed update using PDO, 
Error displayed as below:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in /home/fewatrai/public_html/user_login/myprofile.php:266 Stack trace: #0 /home/fewatrai/public_html/user_login/myprofile.php(266): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/fewatrai/public_html/user_login/myprofile.php on line 266

I know , where is the error comes from, it should be the cause of undefined uid value (which I cannot do how ! )

In the same page, i have displayed all the records with this code :
**along with Image update code:**

```
<?php 
session started..... 
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("select * from tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
.....
<?php echo $row['firstName']?>
......
......
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="update" />
</form>
<?php 
$connectionClass = new Database();
$conn = $connectionClass->dbConnection();
$action = isset( $_POST['action'] ) ? $_POST['action'] : "";
if($action == "update"){
$location  = $_POST['location'];
$path = "images/" . $_FILES['location']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['location']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$path);
$query = 'update tbl_users set location = :location WHERE userID=:uid';
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':location', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
// echo "here should be bindParam for userID field, but i really have no idea on it..";
$stmt->execute(); 
}?>
```

My code pages are as below for db connection and file upload page.

**dbconfig.php**

```
<?php 
class Database
    {
        private $host = "localhost";
        private $user= "root";
        private $pass= "";
        private $db= "pdo_db";
        public $conn;

        public function dbConnection()
            {
                $this->conn = null;    
                try {
                    $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";db=" . $this->db, $this->user, $this->pass);
                    $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
                } catch(PDOException $exception) {
                    echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
                }

                return $this->conn;
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where have you actually set `$conn`? -> `$conn = new Database();`

Comment: Actually, it's probably more like `$db = new Database(); $conn = $db->dbConnection();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$conn is not initialised, use

```
$connectionClass = new Database();
$conn = $connectionClass->dbConnection();
```

this will set $conn...
Also you didnt bind any value to :uid, so

```
$stmt->bindParam(':uid', SET UID VALUE HERE, GIVE TYPE HERE INT OR STRING);
```

Comment: It did helped, But, I have issue (Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in ) , I just wanna to update only image field only out of 9 different field. Is there any way, so that I can update only one image (location) field?

Comment: its because you didnt bind a value to :uid

Comment: add uid and everything will be fine :)
$stmt->bindParam(':uid', ENTER UID VALUE , ENTER TYPE HERE);

Comment: $stmt->bindParam(':uid', userID, PDO::PARAM_INT);... is it userID or $userID?

Comment: Thank you so much @Unni Babu. You helped me a lot.